# Ideas for how to alter file-names of static assets to prevent out-dated browser cached versions of asset files

Tags: php, javascript, css, browser-cache, assets

I have a website that I host with PHPFog. PHPFog, for those who don't know, makes it very easy to deploy an app to multiple application servers with a simple git-push. I would love it if there was some way to automatically update the version number of my javascript/css files with every git-commit or git-push. Or somehow maybe just append the 'build' unix timestamp to the filename. The goal of course to queue browsers to reload the asset file instead of going with the cached version. Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: You can just append a GET variable you alter with every push (like `your.css?someID`), maybe you can alter a file with some variable with post-commit hook, haven't tried that yet in Git though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append a bogus query string to your CSS files - such as

```
styles.css?<?php print $release; ?>
```

The release identifier can be anything you want - perhaps a timestamp, git hashref, or tag.

Comment: Yeah I thought of this after I asked the question, it makes sense. I tested it out and it seems to work. I'm building my project in codeigniter so I think I will make a config file with various 'version' identifiers for various asset groups and have all url requests point towards the asset file with the version appended to it - just like how you mention. And I will only have to change the version # in a single place after I update a file to prevent browsers from using outdated-cached versions.